# DocuSign API callback not sent to application

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

Recently stopped working on new application installation. The application was built in Laravel and from XAMPP installation and Ngrok I am able to create envelopes and to sign them. If application is deployed on any webserver (tested with 2 VPS) callback is not sent at all.

Replacing callback on the online version with Ngrok gave results also on the online Webhook.site I got a callback.

Envelope and Recipients are generated correctly. The code is absolutely the same on the localhost and online version.

Comment: can you check Connect logs on DocuSign admin? to see if there are any issues? also, would check version of TLS

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know for those logs. Only for ones from Privacy and Security.

SSL issue. I am using Let's encrypt. Checking requirements. 

Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: 8c80dd0d-03b9-4d18-b7f1-b1574c85fe96 :: https://example.com/signature/14/callback :: Error - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: well, that sounds like a networking issue. Could be TLS/SSL, could be firewall, could be the request is blocked for a number of reasons on your network.

Comment: I have code example of how to use a listener using Azure/AWS such that the callback is not made directly to your server  if that helps

Comment: After setting up Cloudflare for the domain worked fine. I recently checked SSL during debugging but seemed fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the callback from DocuSign must be able to go through firewall etc. and must used TLS 1.2 or later on your end. The request is probably not making it through because of some networking problem on your network/server.
I would recommend you consider using a method where the request doesn't go to you directly but rather to a cloud provider and you have a listener connected to it.
Here is C# code for this (we have a few other langs options if you need):
https://github.com/docusign/connect-csharp-worker-aws

Here is PHP - https://github.com/docusign/connect-php-worker-aws